# Which article for the English words used in German language?

Tags: article, grammaticality

I have often found "DAS" is used For the English words in German.
e.g.: das Display, das Pixel, das Hotspot... und so on.

Is this a general rule?

Comment: No. Die *Band* (Rock, Jazz,....).

Comment: *Hotspot* is considered masculine by [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hotspot), so even your examples prove the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no rule. It all depends on how the foreign word infiltrated German.

When the word is just a snappy English term for a thing which already exists in German, it gets assigned the same gender:

> shop ≙ der Laden ⇒ **der** Shop.
>
> jet ≙ der Düsenjäger ⇒ **der** Jet. And now all other "jets" are also masculine in German.
>
> airport ≙ der Flughafen ⇒ **der** Airport.

As the last component of compound words determines the gender in German, generalization leads to more obvious gender assignments:

> port ≙ airport ⇒ **der** Port. And now all ports (network ports etc.) are masculine in German.

---

> fashion ≙ die Mode ⇒ **die** Fashion.
>
> party ≙ die Feier ⇒ **die** Party.
>
> rallye ≙ die Wettfahrt ⇒ **die** Rallye.

---

> sandwich ≙ das belegte Brot ⇒ **das** Sandwich.
>
> backup ≙ das Sichern ⇒ **das** Backup.

Comment: Warum *das Fest*?

Comment: @CarstenS: Weil *Fest* aus dem lateinischen *festum* importiert worden ist, und das schon dort Neutrum ist. Siehe den Link von tofro oben für weitere Varianten.

Comment: Und warum hat Feier und nicht Fest das Geschlecht von Party bestimmt? Und ist ein Sandwich nicht eine Art Stulle (oder Schnitte für die von anderswo ;)?

Comment: Es gibt keine Regel. Wie bereits geschrieben muss man jedem Fremdwort einzeln nachjagen, welches existierende Wort es im Sprachgebrauch ersetzt. Vom dem erbt es dann auch das Geschlecht, denn es soll ja ohne große Umstände einfach einsetzbar sein.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule. Quite often, if there is a similar word in German, or the word or parts of it can be translated into German, that article is used. That said, sometimes the gender remains unclear for some time, until usually one article wins out by way of public usage. There can even be regional differences (Austrian German has a slight bias towards *das*, but there certainly isn't any official rule.)

Answer (score 0):

A general tip is that the article for nouns that derive from foreign languages (as well as nouns deriving from verbs, e.g.) is *das*.

However there are many exceptions so all these article tips are just useful for when you have to guess without consulting any linguist sources.

Comment: There is no such rule that I am aware of. Please cite your sources.

Comment: There's no official rule, yes. Sorry for the confusing choice of word. I've edited, it's more like tip that German beginners use.